# Sections of Divisors on Projective Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Everything is over $\Bbb{C}$.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety. Fix an open covering $U_i$ of $X$ and let $D$ be a Cartier divisor given by a collection of rational functions $g_i\in\Bbb{C}(U_i)$, with $g_i/g_j \in \mathcal{O}^\ast(U_i\cap U_j)$.

A section of $D$ is a rational function $s\in\Bbb{C}(X)$ such that $sg_i\in\mathcal{O}(U_i)$. The sections form a vector space, let us denote it with $\mathcal{L}(D)$ here.

Set now $X=\Bbb{P}^n$ and $U_i$ is the standard open covering.

If $D$ is a hypersurface of degree $d$ on $\Bbb{P}^n$, then $\mathcal{L}(D)$ is isomorphic to the vector space $S_d$ of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in $\Bbb{P}^n$.

I understand the proof of this fact by showing the inclusion $S_d\subset\mathcal{L}(D)$ and then using short exact sequences to see that they indeed have the same dimension.

However, when I try to work out some explicit examples I get puzzled:

Let $d=1$, so $D=H$ is a hyperplane, defined by a linear equation $L=0$. As a Cartier divisor, $H=(g_i)$, where $g_i=L/x_i \in\mathcal{O}(U_i)$.
Clearly, any linear polynomial $L'=a_0x_0+\dots+a_nx_n$ yields a section of $H$, by setting $L'\mapsto L'/L\in\Bbb{C}(\Bbb{P}^n)$, since $g_iL'/L=L/x_i$ is regular on $U_i$. However, also forms of higher degree seem to yield a section: if $F$ is a form of degree $d$ then $F\mapsto F/L^d$ is a section as well, since $g_i F/L^d=F/(x_iL^{d-1})$, which is regular on $U_i$. Though, we know that $\dim\mathcal{L}(H)=n+1$.

So my question is: how is it that the section given by $F$ is in fact linearly generated by the linear sections ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the following:

$g_i\frac{F}{x_i^{d-1}L}$ is regular on $U_i$, but $g_j\frac{F}{x_i^{d-1}L}$ is not regular on $U_j$ for $j \neq i$.

You have to choose one *single* $s \in \mathbb C(X)$ and then test $g_is \in \mathcal O(U_i)$ for any $i$. So if your description of $s$ contains an $i$, then $i$ is fixed for now (unless the description is somehow independent of $i$, but this is not the case here) and you have to test the regularity on the opens with another index variable.

By the way: I think you mean $\dim \mathcal L(H)=n+1$.

Comment: Dear @MooS, you are right. And I typed too fast. I edited. Now it should work.

Comment: So, have you got the whole point now?

Comment: Nope, I mean: I did a mistake in the first place, as you noticed :) But know I fixed my example and I don't see where is the missing point. I do have a rational function (now it is well defined), given by $s=F/L^d$, and it satisfies $sg_i$ regular on $U_i$, so it is indeed a section.

Comment: $F/x_iL^{d-1}$ is not regular on $U_i$ for any $i$.. We have $\mathcal O(U_i) = \mathbb C[\frac{x_0}{x_i}, \dotsc, \frac{x_n}{x_i}]$.

Comment: ooops. you are absolutely right. thanks